# How To get Data from Parse database In Android Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, parse-platform

I have a database in Parse, I succeed to connect and receive user ID from Parse DB.

But didn't get inner field of that User ID (i.e. user ID's detail which is stored under that User ID).

Comment: FYI, Parse is going to close. Its better you first switch to other solution. They will be still operating till Jan,17. Read more at http://techcrunch.com/2016/01/28/facebook-shutters-its-parse-developer-platform/#.2udf7j:J7hg

Comment: Thanks, I know that but My client is not want to switch on any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
// for current user details
 // query.whereEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

           query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {


                   //objects = list of all user data
                   //for getting user details 

                   for (int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++) {


                                    String email=objects.get(index).getEmail();
                                    String username=objects.get(index).getUsername();

                                    //if you created custom field in user table i.e "details" 
                                    //String details=objects.get(index).get("details").toString());

        }


                }

            }
        });
```